# Hyperbolic length shortest path (Narrowed question: how to find a specific automorphism of the disk)

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry, automorphism-group

**The short question**:

Given $z_1,z_2$ in the unit disk, and $\gamma(t) $ an arc of a circle that connects them, how can I find an automorphism (a function of the form $ \frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z} $) which maps $z_1$ to $ 0 $, and maps all the arc that connects $z_1,z_2 $ to a segment of the real line?

**Background:**

Define for smooth regular path $ \gamma:[a,b]\to D\left(0,1\right) $ its hyperbolic length:

$$ l\left(\gamma\right):=\intop_{a}^{b}\frac{2|\dot{\gamma}\left(t\right)|}{1-|\gamma\left(t\right)|^{2}}dt $$

I want to show that for any nonzero $ z_{1},z_{2}\in D\left(0,1\right) $ (where $D(0,1)$ denotes the disk in the complex plane which is centered at $0$ with radius $1$) the shortest hyperbolic path is an arc of circle perpendicular to $ C(0,1) $ (the unit circle).

This is actually a part of a bigger question I've been working on.
I'll tell the steps I have done so far:

1. First of all, I proved that $ \frac{1}{z} $ and also all bilinear functions of the form $ \frac{az+b}{cz+d} $

Maps circles and lines in $\mathbb{C} $ to other circles and line/

such that $ \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\in GL_{2}\left(\mathbb{C}\right) $

2.Then, I proved that any function which is automorphism of the disk (i.e a function of the form  $ e^{i\theta}\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z} $ where $|\alpha|<1$), preserves hyperbolic length. That is, for any such $ f $ we have $$ l\left(f\circ\gamma\right)=l\left(\gamma\right) $$

3. And finally, I proved that the shortest path between 0 and $x\in D(0,1)\cap \mathbb{R} $ is a straight line.

Now I have to put the pieces together and prove the original question.

**EDIT**:
My question can be narrowed to the question of existance of an automophism of the disk which maps the arc perpendicular to $C(0,1) $ to the real line inside the unit circle.

Explanation:

if $\gamma $ is a smooth curve which represents an arc of circle perpendicular to $C(0,1)$ which connects between two general $z_1,z_2$ in the unit disk, let $ f $ be an automorphism which maps this arc between $z_1,z_2 $ to the real line (Do we know such automorphism exists?), now, if I could say that such $ f $ really does exists, then  I could say that the image of the composition of $ f $ on any other path connecting between $z_1,z_2 $, does not lie on the real axis, Since an automorphism is conformal mapping, (i.e it preserves angles between curves) so that if another path $\delta $ connecting between $z_1,z_2$ it means that it creates an angle with $\gamma $ at $ z_1 ,z_2 $ and this angle is preserved under the composition of $ f $.
that would end the proof since $ f $ preserves hyperbolic length and the composition between $ f $ and $\gamma $ would be the shortest hyperbolic length.

So if one can promise that such automprhism exists, I would be very thankful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you merely asking for a fractional-linear transformation of the unit disk to itself that maps $z_1$ to $0$ and $z_2$ to a point on the positive real line?

Comment: @Lubin Basically, yes, but it has to be of the form $ \frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z} $ up to a multipication by $e^{i\theta}$ - and not only $z_1$ and $z_2 $ but all of the arc that connects them

Comment: Well, (1) if your beginning arc is part of a circle orthogonal to the circumference of the unit disk, your “not only” is automatically satisfied; and (2) if it maps the disk onto the disk, a fractional-linear transformation is automatically of the shape you specify.

Comment: @Lubin if we'll denote the phase of the complex number $ \frac{z_{2}-z_{1}}{1-\overline{z_{1}}z_{2}} $ as \theta. Will the function $ \frac{z-z_{1}}{1-\overline{z_{1}}z}e^{-i\theta} $ work?

Comment: yes, it will. You’re applying a fractional-linear to a circle that’s orthogonal to the circumference. Since the image passes through $0$, that image is a straight line segment: all geodesics passing through the center are straight lines.